# Connection pools explained in a practical context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Rails' `database.yml` file has a setting, `pool: 5`. I understand what a database connection pool is but I'm being tripped by a few subtleties:

- A connection is used then returned to its pool. The next request can then use a connection from the pool rather than creating a new connection.

  1. How is it determined which request gets which connection?
- Suppose I have a concurrent connections limit of 5 and one of my web pages needs to make 10 queries to the database:

  2. Is each query a separate connection or all 10 queries are considered one connection?
  3. In terms of queries, connections, or speed, what can be an example of a situation that would overwhelm that 5 concurrent connections limit?
- And suppose that, in a different database, I set the database connection pool size to 5.

  4. How are pool size and concurrent connections related, if at all?
  5. In terms of queries, connections, or speed, what can be an example of a situation that would overwhelm this pool size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) ActiveRecord::Base loads a connection when required (lazily on a request or it's current one is closed/disconnected)

2) No, The same connection will be used to make multiple queries

3) No way to answer that without using diagnostic utilities which your db vendor supplied with your db

4) That is db vendor/adapter specific

5) same answer as 3.

If you are experiencing a slow down, the only way to solve them is by using diagnostic tools to inform you where your bottleneck is concurring.  90% of the time, it's not your db or the connections to it (It's usually the indexing, n+1, etc... )

If you are NOT experiencing any slow down, then keep the defaults and move on.  Premature optimization will lead to an over engineered solution

Comment: No. It isn't a matter of premature optimization, I'm just trying to get a picture of how things work. As regards to your answer to #2, so if 100 users requested that web page at the very same second, that's 100 concurrent connections, right?

Comment: No,  pool managers will reuse connections instead of resourcing more if it can.  Even if 1000 requests come in at the same millisecond, some responses will come back before all the requests are dispatched and connections will be reused.